# How to create a global vector in c++

Tags: c++, function, c++11, move-semantics, out-parameters

So, I have this problem. I have two objects, and I need to compare data in each of them, the problem is, when I call a function, I have to send both of them, but my teacher wants me to make it so I could send any object to it, and the vector would get updated, not created anew. Current function:

```
    vector <Muziejus> atrinktiTinkamus(Bakalauras A, Bakalauras B, string R, int m)
{
    vector <Muziejus> X;
    for (int i = 0; i < A.imtiK(); i++){
        if (A.imtiEksponata(i).imtiRusi() == R && A.imtiEksponata(i).imtiKAmz() > m){
            X.push_back(A.imtiEksponata(i));
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < B.imtiK(); i++){
        if (B.imtiEksponata(i).imtiRusi() == R && B.imtiEksponata(i).imtiKAmz() > m){
            X.push_back(B.imtiEksponata(i));
        }
    }
    return X;
}
```

As you can see, I send both of the objects, put them in loops, get what I want, and send the vector back. Although what i need is, for it to be universal, like I send one object, the current vector updates, and goes back, rinse and repeat.. How do I do this?

Comment: Pass a reference to the vector

Comment: Your English sounds excellent, so why are you not coding in English? It sure would help us grok your code a little easier.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost idiomatic C++11 style, if you only would change it to pass large types such as `A`, `B` and `R` by `const&`

```
vector <Muziejus> atrinktiTinkamus(Bakalauras const& A, Bakalauras const& B, string const& R, int m)
{
    vector <Muziejus> X;

    // code reading from A and B, writing to X

    return X; // moved, not copied in C++11
}

auto someX = atrinktiTinkamus(someA, someB, someR, someM);
```

Your teacher seems to want you to use C++98 style "out-parameters" that you pass by reference like this:

```
void // no return type
atrinktiTinkamus(
     Bakalauras const& A, Bakalauras const& B, string const& R, int m, 
     vector<Muziejus>& X // by reference
)
{
    // code reading from A and B, writing to X
}

vector<Muziejus> someX;
atrinktiTinkamus(someA, someB, someR, someM, someX);
```

If you don't reuse the `someX` variable, then the C++11 style is shorter and idiomatic. If however, you can reuse `someX` (and especially the dynamically allocated memory of the `std::vector`), then there can be a performance benefit in using the C++98 style.

**NOTE**: for completeness, there is even a third-style (actually, a variation on the second style) that uses a pointer instead of a reference

```
void // no return type
atrinktiTinkamus(
     Bakalauras const& A, Bakalauras const& B, string const& R, int m, 
     vector<Muziejus>* X // by pointer
)
{
    // code reading from A and B, writing to X
}

vector<Muziejus> someX;
atrinktiTinkamus(someA, someB, someR, someM, &someX);
```

According to some style guides (Google e.g.), the passing of the adress of a variable (`&someX` in this case) makes it easier to spot from the call site when a variable is being modified by a function.

Comment: Yeah, he does. He's old. As hell. Thanks for that. :-)

Comment: @user3042215 there are cases to prefer the out-parameter, and it's good to know both styles.

Comment: @TemplateRex cases such as? I don't see any, to be honest.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz suppose you have a chess program and generate moves into a `vector`. If you have split functions to compute queen, rook, etc. moves, then passing the move `vector` to these subroutines is  more efficient than returning the various vectors by value and concatenating them.

Comment: I'd probably take the output location (iterator) as a parameter then, but I see what you're getting at. Boils down to the fact that C++ is good with mutable data structures, but pretty bad with immutable ones.